# Find $f(1)+f(3)+f(5)+\dots+ f(999)$ where $f$ is a given function

Tags: functions, polynomials, summation, partial-fractions

> Given $$f(x)= \frac {1}
> {\sqrt[3] {x^2+2x+1} + \sqrt[3] {x^2-1} + \sqrt[3] {x^2-2x+1}}$$
>   and 
>   $$E= f(1)+f(3)+f(5)+\dots+ f(999).$$ Then find the value of $E$.

My work :- 
Let $\sqrt[3] {x+1}= a$, $\sqrt[3] {x-1}=b $ 
Then the equation reduces to 
$$f(x)= \frac {1}{a^2+b^2+ab}.$$

Now for this expression I tried breaking into partial fractions to that the sum telescopes to some finite quantity but the cube root terms restrict this straightforward way. Thanks in advance for the help. Also if someone finds a way to rationalize the denominator, please share.

Comment: $\frac{1}{a^2+ab+b^2}=\frac{a-b}{(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)}=\frac{a-b}{a^3-b^3}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both mathlove and Robert Z you method is a very good one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. Since $(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$, it follows that
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{a^2+ab+b^2}=\frac{a-b}{a^3-b^3}=\frac{\sqrt[3] {x+1}-\sqrt[3] {x-1}}{2}.$$
Therefore the given sum is telescopic:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(2k+1)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sqrt[3] {2(k+1)}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sqrt[3] {2k}\right)=\frac{\sqrt[3] {2n}}{2}.$$

Comment: But how does one get that. Actually that is the expression I just expected to be but am not able to get to it.

Comment: because $(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Comment: Thanks a lot to both mathlove and Robert Z your method is a very good one.